# Notify Admin when app crashes in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, user-interaction

I am running an web app and an helper app in parallel. The helper app updates some particular values in database used by the web app. This update happens at fixed time interval by using [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron). Is it possible to notify admin when the helper app breaks?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you please say how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exit` event in helper app, like

```
process.on('exit', function() {
    // handle
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just wondering, can you provide me an idea so that I can notify in the front-end?

Comment: @HassanNomani it should not be any different than other forms of client server communication. Use REST with request polling/ sockets etc.

Comment: Sorted out a way! Thanks!